# Update the reverse Foreign key Model on Model update

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models, Account, Company and Product. Product has an ForeignKey to Company, company and FK to account.
all of them have a field called 'is_active'.

```
class Product(Meta):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Company(Meta):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='account', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What I need:

1. when Company is_active becomes False I want for all Products related to the Company, is_active to become false
2. when Account is_active becomes False I want for all Companies related to the Account, is_active to become false, and also propagate to the Products

I know that I need to change the save(or use post-save signal), but I don't know how to select and change the Foreign Keys Model, and propagate multiple levels down, in case of Account

*The relation is in reverse from parent to child and not from child to parent.*, so no field FK available.

Comment: The reverse relation's instances are accessible at `MODEL_set`, e.g. for a Company instance, you can access all its products at `company_instance.product_set`. Does this answer your question? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#related-objects

Comment: @petr I can use the related name, instead of default, but being a reverse FK, I need to loop thru them and do the save/update on the child model, an in case of accounts propagate further, and I try some stuff but they don't work; maybe you can give me an example on the full question

Comment: You don't need to go further - both of the models will have overridden the `save()` method, meaning when you change the instances one relation away, the others will propagate automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let me show you my solution. First of all you should track changes to the field (in this case "is_active"). To do this in the model's **init**, cached value must be kept and on save the values should be checked: if changed, then update the db:

```
class Company(Meta):
   ...(field definitions)

   def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
       super().__init__(*a, **kw):
       self.__original_is_active = self.is_active

   def save(self, *a, **kw):
      if self.__original_is_active != self.is_active and self.is_active==False:
          # use raw update to perform better than loop
          self.products.update(is_active=False)
      super().save(*a, **kw)
```

**UPDATE (add account change code)**
I suppose that company model has ForeignKey relation to the Account

```
class Account(Meta):
    ...(field definitions)

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        super().__init__(self, *a, **kw)
        self.__original_is_active = self.is_active

    def save(self, *a, **kw):
        if self.__original_is_active != self.is_active and self.is_active == False:
            for company in self.company_set.all():
                company.is_active = False
                company.save()
        super().save(*a, **kw)
```

in case you have the ManyToMany relationship from account to company, then in the save method change the self.company_set.all() to self.companies.all() and that's all.

Your Account model will take similar changes, but don't forget to update companies using for loop, since "update" method won't take effect, because it will directly execute SQL and neglect the "**init**, save" stuff I've done on Company (as [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) say)

Comment: thank you, so you are saying that in case of Account, instead of using "self.companies.update(is_active=False)" to use a for loop; what if in some cases is just one company will updates work ?

Comment: no using update() method, won't call foreign key related object's save method. please look at the docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once) which says the same. So it does not matter how many foreign key related objects you have, you must use for loop (also updated my answer)

Comment: can you please add also the example  the for loop, I tried something but doesn't works as expected